# Finding all domain names that resolve to the same ip?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ip, reverse-dns

Lately I've been tracking a spammer on craigslist. I recently discovered that he's added a new technique to his arsenal, he registered a whole bunch of domain names but they all resolve to the same ip address.

Is there any way to take an ip address and get a list of all the domain names that resolve to that ip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A74.208.74.176) can search on IP address, which tends to work for me.

For example, searching for other things hosting with myipneighbors.com

```
ip:74.208.74.176
```

Returns:

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A74.208.74.176
myipneighbors.com
hotelir.com
```

Comment: Note that this is *not* conclusive and will only contain domains in Bing's index. It'll be a good indicator but you can't rely on it.

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't rely on it as a definitive list.

Answer (score 10):

No.

It's not the way DNS works. You can register any number of domains against a single IP, and not bother putting in a reverse DNS entry for any of them if you want.

Unless you want to brute force resolve the internet. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is. It's not 100%, but it certainly works well enough.

Check out: http://www.net-square.com/msnpawn/index.shtml

There are other tools that do this sort of thing as well, but this will get you going.

Comment: http://www.net-square.com/msnpawn/index.shtml returns a 404 now.

Answer (score 2):

Check out www.myipneighbors.com, it is mostly designed to help people on shared hosting know what other domains are on the same server, but it sounds like it would also apply to what you are trying to do.

Comment: www.myipneighbors.com appears to be dead now.

Answer (score 1):

No, in short.

The only relationship from IP addresses to hostnames (note the direction) is reverse DNS (PTR). Which is a one-to-one mapping and won't assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go.

Be interested to hear if it works for you:

http://www.domaintools.com/reverse-ip/

Comment: That site simply resolves the reverse DNS record (PTR record) for that IP. First of all it will only ever point to a single domainname. Second, even that single result does not have to be meaningful, since it depends on the 'spammer' to register the correct PTR record. How likely is that?

Comment: It does a little more than that. The information is sourced by crawling sites and comparing datasets. It's far from foolproof and is unlikely to be any use at all on obscure or recently registered domains. If you're ever Googled for an IP or ASN then you might have seen Robtex, who among others, perform a similar service for free.