# Is there a way to resolve an IP address to all domains resolving to that IP?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, reverse-dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding all domain names that resolve to the same ip?](https://serverfault.com/questions/34468/finding-all-domain-names-that-resolve-to-the-same-ip)

I am trying to find out if a dedicated server at a hosting site I am using has more than one domain pointing to it through DNS.  Is there a way to do a reverse DNS lookup with my host's IP address such that I can get a list of all domains resolving to my host's IP?  For example, say my host's IP is 1.2.3.4.  There can be multiple domains that resolve to the IP.  Is there a way to tell if there is more than just my domain resolving to that IP?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/34468/finding-all-domain-names-that-resolve-to-the-same-ip) SF question which is pretty much the same as your's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at - http://www.sitedossier.com/ip/66.135.200.145

Just swap out the IP address with one of your choice... It's not 100% all inclusive, but pretty good in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible.
You can only find all PTR entries for the IP but if the guy only add one PTR record you will only get one domain.